# using the querystring parameter in my where clause to generate insert operation

Tags: asp.net

here,using request.Querystring i find the companyname and job title of particular Job.when user logsin using username in texbix.i want the Companyname,jobtitle and username in the same row of a table.But when i generate my query it inserts the (companyName & jobtitle) in the first row and  username in second row.How can i fulfill my task.Some people said,i have to keep the companyname and jobtitle in a variable...then execute.
is it a parfect solution?
if it is,how can i do that?
code:

```
protected void ButtonApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String str = Request.QueryString.Get("JobNo");

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    string apply = "INSERT INTO Company (CompanyName,JobTitle) select CompanyName,JobTitle from Jobs where JobNo='"+str+"'" ; 

    SqlCommand insertApply = new SqlCommand(apply, conn);
    try {
        insertApply.ExecuteScalar();
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("ApplyJob.aspx?JobNo="+str);
    }
```

in the apply.aspx i have following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

string apply = "INSERT INTO Company (CandidateInformation) Values (@CandidateInformation)" ;

SqlCommand insertApply = new SqlCommand(apply, conn);

insertApply.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CandidateInformation", TextBoxaun.Text);
insertApply.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();

Response.Redirect("CompanyInfo.aspx");
```

Comment: i also tried both the query in a single button using two query statement,but that does the same thing

Comment: Have you heard about **SQL Injection** ?? if not please have a look at this article **http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting two times will always result in two new rows.
You can do it all in the first insert statement:

```
string apply = "INSERT INTO Company (CompanyName,JobTitle, CandidateInformation) select 
CompanyName,JobTitle, @CandidateInformation from Jobs where JobNo=@JobNo ;

    SqlCommand insertApply = new SqlCommand(apply, conn);

    insertApply.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CandidateInformation", 
    TextBoxaun.Text);
    insertApply.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNo", str);
            try

            {

                insertApply.ExecuteScalar();

                conn.Close();
                Response.Redirect("CompanyInfo.aspx");


            }
```

Then you won't need the second page.

Comment: I edited to make JobNo a sql paramter to avoid the possibility of SQL injection hacker attacks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Update Company Set CandidateInformation = @CandidateInformation where JobNo='"+str+"'" ;
```

instead of

```
string apply = "INSERTINTO Company (CandidateInformation) Values 
(@CandidateInformation)" ;
```

If you will use `Insert` statement again, then it will always create new record in the table.

`Update` is used to update an already existing record of the table.